# Firebase's internal library of SQLite is conflicting or blocking the CustomSQLite Framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sqlite

I have a custom sqlite framework which uses the spellfix extension of it. The app and frameworks works perfectly fine as long as firebase is not included, the problem arises when firebase messaging is added and it brings in internally sqlite3, which in turn makes the app avoid custom framework for sqlite. Due to this I am unable to use the spellfix extension which is a big requirement.

Is there a way that I can avoid SQLite used by firebase and have the application focus on using the custom framework for it.